# Keep plotly updatemenu button active when changing plot range dynamically in Dash

Tags: python, plotly-dash, plotly-python

I need some advice concerning the `updatemenu` buttons in plotly. I am dynamically changing the plot range of a graph and I trigger different traces with the `updatemenu` buttons. However, as soon as I move the range slider, the default trace is shown again (and the previous button is unselected or not active anymore). I would like the view to stay on the previously selected (via `updatemenu` button) trace.

I spend like 8 hours trying to fix it and this is my last resort :D Otherwise, it won't get fixed.

I do believe tho, that it is possible. I think it is just beyond my skills at the moment. Maybe someone can come up with a clever implementation.

Thanks in Advance :)

### My Ideas

---

1. Property `uirevision`
2. Custom buttons, which modify a global variable
3. Creating an extra callback to listen to the `update` method and saving it in a global variable
4. **Reading out the state of the figure before generating a new one in my callback**
5. Not setting the `visible` property for any trace

*Update: Idea 4 works as intended, see answer below.*

### Some Comments to the Ideas:

1. I thought this might be the easy way. However, when I set it to a constant value, it only saved the zoom/selected data. It didn't keep the previously activated trace visible.
2. By far the most time consuming try due to the variable amount of buttons. I was able to read out which button was pressed, but I couldn't save it in a global variable (I know that it is not recommended, but it doesn't matter here). Even with `dcc.Store` it didn't work, cause the value changed without me modifying it.
3. Somehow it is only possible to listen to the `restyle` and `relayout` method. I wasn't able to toggle the traces with those two methods, therefore I didn't continue.
4. I tried including the figure as a state in the `@ app.callback()` with `dash.State`. However, I wasn't able to get the currently active button.
5. The way I did it at the moment is, that it is working when initialized and one immediately sees a graph when changing the slider. If one doesn't provide the `visible` property, no trace is visible upon changes. Furthermore, I couldn't recreate the wanted behaviour.

### Minimal Working Example (with answer implemented)

---

### Comments on Implementation

The current version of the application is way more complicated. I have many more elements in the callbacks and the dataset is a little more complicated.

Due to changing columns in the dataset, it is important, that I create the traces and the update menu buttons after reading out the columns. It would be easier with a fixed amount and fixed labels/ids.

Imports:

```py
import dash
import dash_core_components as dcc
import dash_html_components as html
import plotly.graph_objects as go
import numpy as np
import webbrowser
import pandas as pd
```

Application:

```py
def launch_app(data) -> None:

    # Creates the Application
    app = dash.Dash(__name__)

    # HTML Layout
    app.layout = html.Div(children=[
        html.Div([
            # Graph Container
            html.Div(id='graph-container'),
            # Range Slider
            html.Div(
                dcc.RangeSlider(id='range-slider', min=0, vertical=True),
            ),
        ], style={"display": "flex", "align-items": "center", "justify-content": "space-evenly"}),
    ])

    # Callback to update graphs when slider changes
    @ app.callback(
        dash.Output("range-slider", "value"),
        dash.Output("graph-container", "children"),
        dash.State("graph-container", "children"),
        dash.Input("range-slider", "value"),
    )
    def update(graph_container, slider):

        # Setting max
        max = len(data["data"]["petal_length"])

        # First call to initialize
        if slider is None:
            end_value = max
            slider_value = [0, end_value]
            return slider_value, update_graphs(0, end_value)

        # Get active Button
        active_button = graph_container[0]['props']['figure']['layout']['updatemenus'][0]['active']

        # Set values depending on the trigger
        start_value = slider[0]
        end_value = slider[1]
        slider_value = slider

        return slider_value, update_graphs(start_value, end_value, active_button)

    # Running the app
    app.run_server(debug=True, port=8050)
```

Generation of new graphs:

```py
def update_graphs(start: int, end: int, active_button: int = 0) -> list[dcc.Graph]:
    """
    Updates the dcc.Graph and returns the updated ones.

    Parameters
    ----------
    start : int
        lower index which was selected
    end : int
        upper index which was selected
    active_button: int
        which button is active of the plotly updatemenu buttons, by default 0

    Returns
    -------
    list[dcc.Graph]
        Updated Graph
    """

    fig = go.Figure()

    # Read out columns automatically
    all_columns = [col for col in list(data["data"].head())]

    # Generate X-Axis
    xvalues = np.arange(0, len(data["data"]["petal_length"]))

    # CREATION OF TRACES
    for ii, col in enumerate(all_columns):
        if ii == active_button:
            visible = True
        else:
            visible = False
        fig.add_trace(
            go.Scatter(x=xvalues[start: end],
                       y=data["data"][f"{col}"][start: end],
                       visible=visible)
        )

    # Generation of visible array for buttons properties
    show_list = []
    for ii, val in enumerate(all_columns):
        # Initialization
        temp = np.zeros(len(all_columns))
        temp[ii] = 1
        temp = np.array(temp, dtype=bool)
        show_list.append(temp)

    # CREATION OF BUTTONS
    all_buttons = []

    for ii, col in enumerate(all_columns):
        all_buttons.append(dict(label=f"{col}", method="update", args=[
            {"visible": show_list[ii]},
            {"yaxis": {'title': f'yaxis {col}'}}
        ]))

    # Update Menu Buttons
    fig.update_layout(
        updatemenus=[
            dict(
                type="buttons",
                active=active_button,
                showactive=True,
                buttons=all_buttons,
                x=0.0,
                y=1.2,
                xanchor="left",
                yanchor="top",
                direction="right",
            )
        ])

    return [
        dcc.Graph(
            id='time',
            figure=fig,
        )
    ]
```

Script:

```py
if __name__ == "__main__":

    # Loading sample Data
    iris = pd.read_csv(
        'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/mwaskom/seaborn-data/master/iris.csv')
    data = {"id": 20, "data": iris}

    # Opens the server
    webbrowser.open("http://127.0.0.1:8050/")
    # Launches the server
    launch_app(data)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your idea (4) to include your figure (or its parent object) as a state in your callback function `update` should work. You only have to find the correct "active" property and then pass on the active button as an argument to your `update_graphs` function.

The following changes should do the job:

1. Add "graph-container" as input.

```py
@ app.callback(
        dash.Output("range-slider", "value"),
        dash.Output("graph-container", "children"),
        dash.Input("graph-container", "children"),
        dash.Input("range-slider", "value"),
    )
    def update(graph_container, slider):
```

2. Get the current active button's index and pass it to `update_graphs`.

```py
active_button = graph_container[1]['props']['figure']['layout']['updatemenus'][0]['active']

return slider_value, update_graphs(start_value, end_value, active_button=active_button)
```

3. Receive active_button index in `update_graphs` and use it.

```py
def update_graphs(start: int, end: int, active_button: int):
  # Some stuff
  # Update Menu Buttons
    fig.update_layout(
        updatemenus=[
            dict(
                # other stuff
                active=active_button,
                
            )
        ])
```